# How to Unauthenticated routes using amplify authenticator component in angular

Tags: angular, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Like the title states, all docs for the amplify authenticator component have it wrapping app-component.  I wish to have routes which are not authenticated, and I don't want to prompt users to login unless I direct them to my signing component.  I understand I could do it all custom, create a service class and call signing myself, but I figured I would use the authenticator component since it's readily available. Is this possible?  I tried add authenticatorp-component to a child component in an angular route and I get errors of missing form fields.

> Blockquote ERROR TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'country_code' of '(0 , *actor_mjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0*_.getActorContext)(...)' as it is undefined.

By the way adding the child component directly to app.component works, the issue is if we access the child component via routes.

Comment: Could you re-write the question, and add some code? What's your goal?

Comment: As the question states, I want to be able to display the signin prompt in a specific route, child component.  Not wrapping the whole app, which forces all users to authenticate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake all along.  The child component I had created for my signinpage happened to be named the same as a component in Amplify module.  The wrong component was imported into routes.

You can add this code, into a child component

```
<amplify-authenticator>
  <ng-template amplifySlot="authenticated" let-user="user" let-signOut="signOut">
    <h2>Welcome, {{ user.username }}!</h2>
    <button (click)="signOut()">Sign Out</button>
  </ng-template>
</amplify-authenticator>
```

Answer (score 0):

To enable conditional logic for specific pages requiring authentication, you can wrap your child component with the same logic as the [example](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/js/#option-1-use-pre-built-ui-components) shows to wrap the whole app.

```
import { withAuthenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";

const ExamplePage = () => {
  return (
    <AuthenticatedByGroup>
      <ChildComponent />
    </AuthenticatedByGroup>
  );
};

export default withAuthenticator(ExamplePage );
```

Comment: unfortunately I had seen that documentation but it is React specific.  I need a solution for Angular